# Why a scalar function call for string splitting can lead to session block?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, sqlperformance

Recently, we monitored a very strange issue about SQL Server session block, there was a scalar function for string splitting process which used in a loop code block within the stored procedure, we've checked the code, there was no any operations on database tables, why other sessions were blocked by the session that invoking the function?

here is the function definitions:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[splits](@SourceSql varchar(max), @StrSeprate varchar(10), @y int)
 returns varchar(max) as
begin
    declare @i int
    declare @idx int
    declare @s varchar(max)
    if(right(@SourceSql,1)!=@StrSeprate)begin
        set @SourceSql=@SourceSql+@StrSeprate
    end
    set @idx=0
    set @i=charindex(@StrSeprate,@SourceSql)
    while @i>=1
    begin
        set @s=left(@SourceSql,@i-1)
        set @SourceSql=substring(@SourceSql,@i+1,len(@SourceSql)-@i)
        set @i=charindex(@StrSeprate,@SourceSql)
        set @idx=@idx+1
        if (@idx=@y) begin
            break
        end
        set @s=null
    end
    return @s
end
```

Comment: " there was a scalar function for string splitting process" - that's your first problem, but too little info to answer more fully.

Comment: UDTTs and table-valued parameters have existed in the product for over a decade. Why are you still passing multiple values around in a type (`varchar(max)`) that's not **designed** for holding multiple values?

Answer (score 0):

This function can not cause the blocking on your instance. You can check other previous operation over same Session\Request.

But, I can help you with other option, instead of this function. Below one is for Splitting Integer values but you can use for VARCHAR as well with changing the datatype.

```
DECLARE @ids NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'115676,115678,115679,115680,115681'
DECLARE @input_xml XML
SELECT @input_xml = Cast('<root><x>'+ Replace(@ids, ',', '</x><x>')+ '</x></root>' AS XML)    

SELECT f.x.value('.', 'BIGINT') AS Id
FROM @input_xml.nodes('/root/x') f(x)
```